# How to match group of words divided by "-" using a regexp in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7, and I'm trying to match a certain string with this structure:

```
INPUT = 'abc-1-2 abc-2-3 abc-1-1 - TYP1 xyz-2-3 xyzzz - TYP2 ooop-1-1 abc-3-3 bbb - TYP3'

EXPECTED_OUTPUT = [
    'abc-1-2 abc-2-3 abc-1-1 - TYP1',
    'xyz-2-3 xyzzz - TYP2',
    'ooop-1-1 abc-3-3 bbb - TYP3']
```

This the solution that I tryed but it does not work:
**[Online Demo](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5B%5E%20%5D%2B%20)%2B-%20%5B%5E%20%5D%2B&test_string=abc-1-2%20abc-2-3%20abc-1-1%20-%20TYP1%20xyz-2-3%20xyzzz%20-%20TYP2%20ooop-1-1%20abc-3-3%20bbb%20-%20TYP3&ignorecase=1&multiline=1&dotall=1&verbose=1)**

Comment: Please explain what is the rule to split the string as well as restriction and possible scenarios.

Comment: @DYZ's answer is good, but I'd clarify what you mean in case someone else has a good solution. Are the strings delimited by the `TYP\d` keyword?

Comment: There is no keyword TYP. My example is not generic enough. The word which follows '- ' can be anything except spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
".+?TYP\d+"
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the trailing `+?`?

Comment: If I use "(.+?[^ ]+)+?" instead of "(.+?TYP\d)+?" because the word following '- ' is generic, does not work.

Comment: @ekhumoro "Repeated several times" (unless it is exactly three times, and then `+?` must become `{3}`.

Comment: @edmondPlutone I am not sure what "generic" means for you.

Comment: @DYZ. I know what it means - but what is the purpose of it in your example? If you remove it, `re.findall` it will produce exactly the same output. So it's not clear to me why you think you need it.

Answer (score 1):

The following *regex* should do it :

```
\b.*?-\s.*?(?:\s|$)
```

*see **[demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hCWuF3/2)***

**python**

```
import re
regex = ur"\b.*?-\s.*?(?:\s|$)"
str = "abc-1-2 abc-2-3 abc-1-1 - TYP1 xyz-2-3 xyzzz - TYP2 ooop-1-1 abc-3-3 bbb - TYP3"
matches = re.finditer(regex, str)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    print ("{match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\S.*? - \S+', INPUT)
['abc-1-2 abc-2-3 abc-1-1 - TYP1', 'xyz-2-3 xyzzz - TYP2', 'ooop-1-1 abc-3-3 bbb - TYP3']
```

Explanation:

```
'\S'  # any non-space character
'.*?' # (.) any character (*) zero or more times (?) non-greedy (match as few as possible)
' - ' # literal space dash space
'\S'  # any non-space character
'+'   # one or more times
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see is a unbroken/broken sequence matched with
`[^\s-]+(?:-?[^\s-])*(?:\s+[^\s-]+(?:-?[^\s-])*)*\s+-\s+[^\s-]+`

[Online Demo](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5E%5Cs-%5D%2B(%3F%3A-%3F%5B%5E%5Cs-%5D)*(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5B%5E%5Cs-%5D%2B(%3F%3A-%3F%5B%5E%5Cs-%5D)*)*%5Cs%2B-%5Cs%2B%5B%5E%5Cs-%5D%2B&test_string=abc-1-2%20abc-2-3%20abc-1-1%20-%20TYP1%20xyz-2-3%20xyzzz%20-%20TYP2%20ooop-1-1%20abc-3-3%20bbb%20-%20TYP3&ignorecase=1&multiline=1&dotall=1&verbose=1)

```
 [^\s-]+                # Unbroken sequence XXX-XXX-XXX
 (?:
      -?
      [^\s-] 
 )*

 (?:                    # Optional sequence  <space> XXX-XXX-XXX
      \s+ 
      [^\s-]+ 
      (?:
           -?
           [^\s-] 
      )*
 )*
                        # Broken sequence   <space> - <space> XXX
 \s+                    # Space
 -                      # Dash
 \s+                    # Space
 [^\s-]+                # XXX
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 30 ) 
abc-1-2 abc-2-3 abc-1-1 - TYP1  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 31 , len 20 ) 
xyz-2-3 xyzzz - TYP2  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 52 , len 27 ) 
ooop-1-1 abc-3-3 bbb - TYP3
```

Comment: I guess this is overly complicated if there's always `TYP\d+` in the strings.

Comment: @Jan - You would think so right. But I see all these answers with `.*?` in them and wonder why the need for a regex at all.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be:

```
import re

string = "abc-1-2 abc-2-3 abc-1-1 - TYP1 xyz-2-3 xyzzz - TYP2 ooop-1-1 abc-3-3 bbb - TYP3"

rx = re.compile(r'(.+?TYP\d)\s*')
parts = rx.findall(string)
print(parts)
# ['abc-1-2 abc-2-3 abc-1-1 - TYP1', 'xyz-2-3 xyzzz - TYP2', 'ooop-1-1 abc-3-3 bbb - TYP3']
```